# How to set default auto mount options for removable media?

Tags: mount, automounting, removable-storage

I have quite a bit of removable media (flash drives, external hard drives, etc) that I want to adjust auto mount options for. How does one do this? Is there something similar to `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Which desktop environment?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33461) about this. Basically it says that setting "global" auto mount options is currently not possible. You need to have root privilege and set `/etc/fstab` manually (udisks will read it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to specify automount options across any DE you can specify this with `udisks` configuration: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Udisks

Something such as:

`udisks --mount /dev/sda1 --mount-options options`

`autofs` also works: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs

Comment: udisks is deprecated, can you please update your answer for udisks2 ?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is now available in [udisks2](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/) since version 2.9.0.
See the documentation [here](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html) for how to configure default and allowed mount options.

Comment: I currently use Ubuntu 18 which uses udisks2 2.7, can I set default mount options there?