# mounting removable USB disks with nodev,noexec,nosuid

Tags: mount, usb, usb-drive

When I want to use a USB disk on my desktop, I insert the disk and mount it manually, for example:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

I know that I can specify mount options with `-o`, such as

```
mount -o nodev,noexec,nosuid /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

But is there a way to set default options for all USB disks?
(so that I don't have to type it manually every time)

Comment: I am not sure if you would be interested in using `udisks` as discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101634/how-to-set-default-auto-mount-options-for-removable-media)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In attempting to ascertain whether this is a duplicate of the [U&L Q&A asked by @Ramesh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101634/how-to-set-default-auto-mount-options-for-removable-media) I came across this Ask Fedora Q&A titled: [udisks default mount options](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9957/udisks-default-mount-options/). One of the answer to that Q&A said the following:

*excerpt - https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9957/udisks-default-mount-options/?answer=23126#post-id-23126*

> I've had a [similar discussion in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=885116). Basically mount options
>   are hard-coded in udisk but if you add a device in fstab, it will
>   mount with the options and at the mount point specified in fstab.
>
> Too bad there is no way to override in udisks2

So it would seem your options are to either setup entries in `/etc/fstab` for your removable media, or attempt to use `udisks`, which will make use of it's own unconfigurable default options, or make use of the ones that you'd have to define in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: using `/etc/fstab` has two problems: 1) I don't know what filesystem the disk will have (it could be fat or ext4). I am not sure whether i can leave taht out in fstab. 2) I think, I cannot use wildcards in fstab, i.e. `/dev/disk/by-path/pci-*-usb*`

Comment: @MartinVegter - correct you'd have to know these things ahead of time in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @MartinVegter - do you care if the devices are automatically mounted w/ those options when the device becomes present?

Comment: not automatically. I am happy to mount them manually, I just don't want to have to type the long options every time.

Comment: @MartinVegter - what about these methods? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134797/how-to-automatically-mount-an-usb-device-on-plugin-time-on-an-already-running-sy/134903#134903

Comment: the methods are for automount. I don't need automount.

Comment: is there any way to change the `defaults` options. Where are they defined?

Comment: @MartinVegter - the methods can be setup to identify the devices but not perform the actual automounts, as in my A.

Comment: is there a way to mount all devices which are not specifically listed in `/etc/fstab` with options `nodev,noexec,nosuid` ? i.e. changing the defaults.